# Incrementing a std_logic_vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I begin VHDL and I have a little problem. I want to add 1 to a std_logic_vector. I saw that this question has already been asked but it still doesn't work. This is what I do

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lesson10c is 
  port (signal calculateur :  std_ulogic_vector (1 downto 0));
end lesson10c;

architecture behaviour of lesson10c is
begin 
  calculateur <= "00";

  process(calculateur)
  begin
    for i in 0 to 3 loop
    calculateur <= std_ulogic_vector(unsigned(calculateur)+1);
    end loop;
  end process;

end behaviour;
```

The error is

> Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "calculateur[1]" at numeric_std_vhdl1993.vhd(1244)".

It's just a practising code without interest. Can you tell me where I'm wrong please?

Comment: Hi Jean, welcome to SO! Please have a look here in order to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please also learn how to format your posts.

Comment: Just use an `integer` type and add 4... Why make it difficult

Comment: Duplicate of [Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net... VHDL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061596/error-10028-cant-resolve-multiple-constant-drivers-for-net-vhdl-error). Note what Quartus [reports on the error](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vdb_net_multiple_drivers.htm) and the error also demonstrates you could simulate before synthesis. With a resolved data type you'd get 'X's, and unresolved data type results in errors in simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is more fundamental than incrementing a `std_logic_vector`. You seem to think you are writing software. You are not, you are designing hardware.

Each process (whether explicit or implicit) in VHDL infers a lump of hardware. You have two processes: one is explicit (`process(calculateur)`), the other implicit (`calculateur <= "00";`). Both are driving the signal `calculateur`. Therefore you have a short circuit.

Your error message is because you have this short circuit. However, it's worse than that: your second process also has *combinational feedback* (its output is connected to its input) and also you will find that that second process does not increment `calculateur` four times (which I guess is what you were hoping).

Not only that, the error message you cite is an error message from a logic synthesiser, which suggests you are trying to synthesise your code without having simulated it. (I say that, because I can't believe that the output of any simulation of this code would be what you would be how you would want your code to behave). Always simulate your code first.

I think you need to take a step back and learn some VHDL fundamentals. [My company's website](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is due to your code driving `calculateur` in two different processes. Remember that this is a hardware description language, not a programming language.

```
calculateur <= "00";

process(calculateur)
begin
  for i in 0 to 3 loop
  calculateur <= std_ulogic_vector(unsigned(calculateur)+1);
  end loop;
end process;
```

The first line here is a concurrent assignment. There's nothing wrong with this, but it is really a shorthand for another process.

With that in mind, we can see that `calculateur` is driven from within two processes. Each process that sets a signal creates a driver for that signal, and pretty much any synthesis tool does not allow multiple drivers. This is what the error message means.