# VHDL err: 10028: Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have a code like this:

```
signal      IndexA_1    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal      IndexA_2    : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

type        Register_array_type     is array (0 to 255) of 
std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal      RegArray                : Register_array_type; 

IndexA_1 <= data_in1;
IndexA_2 <= data_in2;

RegArray(1) <=  x"00000000_0000000b";
RegArray(2) <=  x"00000000_0000000c";
RegArray(3) <=  x"00000000_0000000d";
RegArray(4) <=  x"00000000_0000000e";
RegArray(5) <=  x"00000000_0000000f";

RegArray(to_integer(unsigned(IndexA_1(7 downto 0))))  <= Rx_data_1 ;
RegArray(to_integer(unsigned(IndexA_2(7 downto 0))))  <= Rx_data_2 ;
```

So for example I want to assign part of the RegArray to some fixed value and the other part of the array get the data from Rx_data_x. So in the code, I know that IndexA_1 will not have the index overlapped with the fixed ones (in the code it will never be 1,2,3,4,or 5). But I got an multiple drivers error (Because Quartus thinks IndexA_1&2 may overlap with 1,2,3,4,5). Any idea how to code for this can avoid the err?

Thanks!

Comment: I have not tried but I would add an offset of 5 to index: `RegArray(5+...`. Then subtract 5 from indexA_1 and IndexA_2.

Comment: *Longest static prefix* (IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names 8.1 para 7. The unnamed integer values indexing RegArray created by conversion of a slice of non-static values have overlapping ranges with the static indexed assignments. These assignments are in separate processes and you have multiple drivers. Move all  the assignments into the same process or create integer variables/signals for the non-static ranges with a range constraint. Provide a [mcve]. The problem should show up in simulation, static indexed values with 'X's when read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net... VHDL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061596/error-10028-cant-resolve-multiple-constant-drivers-for-net-vhdl-error)

Comment: So many existing questions for this error

Comment: Yeah I know where the err is.. Just asking is there a smart coding method to solve this. Thanks